# Inline assembly is not producing my desired result with clang

Tags: assembly, clang, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am using inline assembly x86_64 with clang. I want the *exact* assembly compiled into my binary that I specify in my source code, but for some reason clang keeps on changing it. **This only happens when I use AT&T GCC style assembly, this does not happen with MSVC `__asm`** I want to use AT&T style assembly because the rest of my code uses AT&T style a lot and I want to keep things consistent. This is how my assembly code is declared:

```
__attribute__((naked)) void XxInternalOperation()
{
    asm volatile("mov %%rcx, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%r11\n\t"
        "jmpq *%%r11"
        :
        : "r" (jumpAddrAbsolute)
        : "r11");
}
```

I want my assembly code to represent this intel code:

```
mov rax, rcx
mov r11, jmpAddrAbsolute ; <-- this is an unsigned long long variable
jmp r11
```

But a quick dissasembly in IDA shows something else:

```
mov rax, cs:jumpAddrAbsolute
mov rax, rcx
mov r11, rax
jmp r11
```

Is there a way to get the exact assembly code I want?

Comment: Extended asm isn't supposed to be supported at all in `naked` functions, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes.  Either take away the `naked` and put up with the prologue and setup code inserted by the compiler, or hardcode the address yourself.   And it sounds like you don't want `jumpAddrAbsolute` put in a register, so the "r" constraint is probably not what you want, more likely "i" though I am not certain.

Comment: @NateEldredge Let me edit my question real quick

Comment: Actually it looks like it does work, my test was bogus.  I think I can answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, I don't want it in a register. Unfortunately, `i` isn't working either.

Comment: @NateEldredge. Hmm, can you show me? It doesn't seem to work on my end.

Comment: Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/G37qY5) what you wanted?

Comment: @NateEldredge That would be perfect, except `jumpAddrAbsolute` is an unsigned long long global variable. If I try to compile that with `jumpAddrAbsolute` being a variable, it throws a compile error.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want, then.  Are you trying to load r11 with the address of  the symbol jumpAddrAbsolute (as an immediate move), or with its contents (as an indirect move)?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm concerned about your solution since the documentation says "While using extended asm [...] may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported."

Comment: @NateEldredge With the contents; an indirect move. Because I'll be jumping to whatever value is stored in `jumpAddrAbsolute`, as `jumpAddrAbsolute ` is calculated at runtime.

Comment: If the latter then perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/r8733n), which appears to work though as Joseph says there are no guarantees.

Comment: I was confused because in Intel syntax that would normally be `mov r11, [jumpAddrAbsolute]` but that's not what you wrote.

Comment: What's your code model?  Will `jumpAddrAbsolute` have an absolute 32-bit address, or 32-bit relative offset from rip?  If you want to do it as basic asm you have to handle this yourself.

Comment: @NateEldredge `jumpAddrAbsolute` will contain the 64-bit absolute address of where I want to jump to. No offset from the current instruction pointer; it's an absolute address.

Comment: No, I mean the address of the `jumpAddrAbsolute` variable itself.

Comment: Oh my bad, it'll have an 32 bit relative address offset from the instruction pointer @NateEldredge

Comment: Okay then perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hcnx48) is what you want.

Comment: Rather than coersce the C compiler to generate the code, how about creating a separate assembly module (assemble it with `as`) that contains the code for `XxInternalOperation`

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, that works perfectly! If you could make that an answer that'd be great.

Comment: I wouldn't use @NateEldredge solution because GCC doesn't guarantee it will work in all cases. The [manual for extended inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) states _Accessing data from C programs without using input/output operands (such as by using global symbols directly from the assembler template) may not work as expected._ . While you can use it, it isn't always guaranteed to work and the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: You use the `r` operand specifier for `%0`.  No surprise clang picks a register!  If you want an immediate, use an appropriate specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang does not “change” your assembly.  It does exactly what you ask it to do and that is: it picks a *register* (that's what the `r` constraint means) and substitutes `%0` for it.  Note that this register can also be `rax` in which case your code won't work.  If you want clang to pick a memory operand, use the `m` constraint instead.  Refer to [the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for details on gcc-style inline assembly.  Here's an example:

```
extern unsigned long long jumpAddrAbsolute;

__attribute__((naked)) void XxInternalOperation()
{
    asm volatile("mov %%rcx, %%rax\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%r11\n\t"
        "jmpq *%%r11"
        :
        : "m" (jumpAddrAbsolute)
        : "r11", "rax");
}
```

This compiles to:

```
movq    %rcx, %rax
movq    jumpAddrAbsolute(%rip), %r11
jmpq    *%r11
```

which seems what you want.

Note that I have marked `rax` as clobbered since you use it in the first instruction.  Note further that there is no guarantee that `rcx` holds any particular value when this inline assembly statement is executed.  The compiler is free to set it to whatever value it likes.

Note also that the compiler may possibly decide to inline `XxInternalOperation` in which case your indirect jump will have the unintended side effect of performing a tail call in the caller.  Consider marking the function as `noinline` to avoid this scenario.

In general though, performing jumps or calls in inline assembly is often a sign of a wrong approach and usually leads to all sorts of problems.  If you have some details about the problem that you have decided to solve using this inline assembly, I might be able to suggest a better solution to you.

Comment: Using extended inline assembly within the body of a naked function is not supported (safely) by GCC per the documentation. _**Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions** (see Basic Asm). While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported._ https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#x86-Function-Attributes

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Good thing OP is programming in clang.  I'll have to see if there's any problem with that when clang is used.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Though yes, I agree that entire functions should be written in plain old assembly instead of inline assembly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch @fuz That's true, so I've done what you mentioned earlier and rewritten this in a separate assembly source file and compiled & linked via `as`. It works well too.

Comment: @fuz I'll be accepting this as the answer because it does what I originally asked for.

Comment: @ArushAgarampur Cool!  Always happy to help.

Comment: I think `__attribute__((naked))` implies noinline.  The compiler doesn't know if it ends with a `ret` or not because naked implies the compiler shouldn't emit one, leaving that up to the asm.  My understanding of `naked` is that it's mostly equivalent to writing the function in a `.s` file, but makes C++ name mangling easy, and lets the definition also be a declaration for C/C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I thought of that while I was writing my assembly in a completely different source, and eventually decided to stick to inline ASM.